# Printing multiple pdf's causes printer to pause between print jobs

Tags: finder, pdf, printing

I'm printing thousands of PDF documents.

If I select them in the Finder and press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>, it creates each PDF as a print job. However, the printer takes a huge pause - maybe 10 sec between each print job, and the printing becomes very slow.

To combat this I'm merging the PDF documents into one single PDF, which makes the printing very fast, however this is not ideal.

Is it possible to print multiple documents through the Finder without a delay between print jobs?

My printer is a [Brother HL-3140CW](https://www.brother-usa.com/products/HL3140CW).

Comment: What printer (brand/model) are you printing to? How is it connected? Does it normally print pretty much at once or might the 10 second delay be from transferring the document from the computer to the printer?

Comment: I'm using Brother hl-3140cw. I connect it through wifi. When I combine all the documents into one pdf, it's printing very fast. I would think that the printer has some sort of buffer to the next document ready when completing the print.

Comment: Hello Gauz, welcome to Ask Different. Are the PDF documents you print mainly text or do they have pictures or graphics (or you think this is in irrelevant to your problem)? How long does it take for the printer to start printing when sending the PDFs as a single document (also 10 sec, longer?)? What does the print queue display during the 10 sec delay, is it transferring data or it waits until the printer responds (see https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204135)?

Comment: Hi, jaume, thx for taking the time. My pdf's are invoices so the content is a mix of text and usually some logo. From starting the print on the computer it usually takes approximately 10-15 sec to actually start printing.

When printing multiple pdf's the print queue displays "waiting for job to complete" for maybe 7-8 seconds after the paper is out of the printer. Meanwhile the printer turns off the fan and goes into standby mode for like 2-3 sec until it starts up again.